# Is it possible to call overwritten methods in child class from the parent class?

Tags: oop, inheritance, dependencies, uml

Assume we have a parent class A and a child class B inheriting from it. A has the method m() which is overwritten by B. Let's also assume we have a third class C, which has call-dependency to class A. Is it possible for C to call the overwriting method m() from class B in UML2?

Comment: I forgot to mention that the question relates to UML2

Comment: You may always improve the text of your question. This time, I have done it for you :-)  I have added "...in UML2" at the end of your question.

Comment: What is a call dependency? Is C also inherited from A?

Comment: Reading your question once more (after having read it many times before already) I still have my doubts about your issue. So I vote t close this. Maybe you can provide a class diagram about the inheritance (like it's provided in the answers) and update your question.

Answer (score 0):

This clearly depends on the language you are using. Personally I don't know of any language that allows that. Instead you would likely (generally) have an operation in `B` that offers the pure functionality of `B`'s superclass' method:

[image]

And the call sequence could be like

[image]

Comment: I recall there are some but I don't remember them on the spot. There is also some language where the method used depends on the type of the variable. To me its insane, but...

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I was talking about UML.

Comment: @Ister Yes, I have the same feeling :-) Contradict to any encapsulation paradigm

Comment: If I read the question correctly, volkan15 does not want to execute the functionality implemented by class A, but only the functionality implemented by class B, that replaces the functionality of class A.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl Hmm. He writes "the overwriting method" which seems trivial since that's what you see anyway. So I assumed he acutally meant "the overridden method" like what he asks in the title.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in UML2 and in most OO programming languages, like C++, C# and Java, it is possible that C executes behavior that calls method m of B.

In terms of UML, if you have this class diagram:

[image: classdiagram]

then this is a valid sequence diagram:

[image: seqdiagram]

Method `callM` is implemented such that it calls `p.m()`. When you call `callM`, you may pass an actual parameter of type B, because it's compatible with formal parameter p of type A. The effect of `p.m()` will then be that the overridden method m in B will be called. This is also known as polymorphism.

```
class A {
    public m();
}
class B extends A {
    public m();
}
class C {
    public callM ( p : A ) {
        p.m();    // calls either A::m or B::m, depending on actual type of p
    }
}
b = new B;
c = new C;
c.callM(b);   // let c call method m of class B
```

For more examples, [click here for online study material](http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~cs3443/notes/chapter10/ch10.html)

Comment: Where is the inheritance the OP asks about?

Comment: Allright, I have added the declarations of A and B as well.

Comment: That's just what I wrote. You **can't** call it. You need an operation which calls the native super operation.

Comment: Those circles in the classes you use are probably put there be some Mickeysoft tool (or is that Rational?). But that's in no way UML standard, except for that tool vendor :-/

Comment: It's plantuml.com. I didn't have EnterpriseArchitect with me, so I had to fall back on an online tool.

Comment: Jup. I just wanted to note that. Cheers.